# Angular method afterClosed of MatDialog not called

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component in which I open a MatDialog when clicking a button. The I want to do operations when the dialog closes. This is what I did:

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.width = "60%";
dialogConfig.autoFocus=true;
let dialogRef = this.dialog
  .open(MyDialogComponent, dialogConfig)
  .afterClosed()
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log("Dialog closed");
});
```

but nothing is printed on the console.

Comment: i think you have to follow this link https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Comment: I've already done what's said there, but not working

Comment: If it's not working, then reproduce the issue on a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com.

Answer (score 0):

In the MyDialogComponent, inject a MatDialogRef into it's constructor e.g.

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>){}
```

and then explicity close it e.g. using a button click event in the template or something similar:

In template:

```
<button (click)="onCancelClicked()">Cancel</button>
```

In component:

```
onCancelClicked(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Not entirely sure why it's not working the way you have it but the above is the way I've always done it.  Perhaps you need to explicitly call the close() function.

Comment: Yes I already have this in my DialogComponent, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7ynft). From your code I can't see the mistake. Please consider renaming dialogRef as it is the subscription, and not the reference to your dialog.